# Impossible to wget a link with php redirection

Tags: php, downloads, wget, curl

I tried all the tricks I could find to download this link from terminal using wget and curl :
http://libgen.gs/ads.php?md5=5C757EA95B47CEAB5065B26EEB55896A

None succeeded to get me the epub book that I can simply download by clicking 'get' button when opening the link in a browser. I rather download it using consol, is it even possible to do so ?

Comment: `wget` and `curl` actually worked fine for me. What exactly was the command you've typed?

Comment: it works the way @mondotofu did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to open the link you've been given.  You'll probably notice something that says "GET" at the top of your web page

Use wget on that link.

```
wget "http://111.90.145.72/get.php?md5=5c757ea95b47ceab5065b26eeb55896a&key=FIS7AXJH8YP1OC66"
```

It will put that in your current directory.  The last thing you have to do is rename the file.

```
mv 'get.php?md5=5c757ea95b47ceab5065b26eeb55896a&key=FIS7AXJH8YP1OC66' random.epub
```

Then you can open your epub file in an ebook reader.

Comment: oh amazing ! This solves the problem. Actually I did the first part but I just ignored the output because it was not epub extension. It turns output I only needed to rename. Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 1):

@mondotofu got close to the right answer.

Your problem isn't PHP redirection. You need recursion. The link you provided yields a static HTML page with another link to the actual content. In order to get to the content you need to follow the link manually. Or use Wget's recursion options to do it automatically.

The main thing mondotofu missed was using `--content-disposition` in order to ask Wget to use the name provided by the server which gets you the right filename instead of needing to use `mv`

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck using `curl` to do this instead of `wget`, and set it to follow the redirection using the switches `-L`, `-J`, and `-O`.

```
curl -O -J -L http://libgen.gs/ads.php?md5=5C757EA95B47CEAB5065B26EEB55896A
```

A bit of info on these switches from [the documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
-O/--remote-name
  Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get. 
  (Only the file part of the remote  file  is  used, the path is cut off.)

-L/--location
  (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the  server  reports that the requested page has moved 
  to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX 
  response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new 
  place.  If  used together  with  -i/--include  or -I/--head, headers from 
  all requested pages will be shown. When authentication is used, curl only 
  sends its credentials to the initial host. If a redirect takes curl to a 
  different host, it  won't be  able  to  intercept  the  user+password. 
  See also --location-trusted on how to change this. You can limit the
  amount of redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs option.

-J/--remote-header-name
  (HTTP) This option tells the -O/--remote-name option to  use  the  
  server-specified  Content-Disposition  filename instead of extracting a 
  filename from the URL.
```

Comment: That doesn't solve OPs issue at all